# What color names does Microsoft Outlook 365 support?

Tags: outlook

I set the background color of a formatted email message to `#ffffff`. When I examine the HTML that Outlook produces for the email, I see `bgcolor="white"`.

If I set the background color to `#fffff0` then the HTML contains `bgcolor="ivory"`.

So, Microsoft supports `white` and `ivory`. What others?

Does Microsoft publish the set of color names and their corresponding RGB values that is supported in Outlook 365?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can pretty much use any color combination you like using Hex formatting like in your example.  A bit like if you are editing any Office document, email etc and you pick the 'More colors' option from the drop-down list and set the value using RGB.

Comment: These are HTML colour names, not Microsoft's.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Color_keywords